# Test if a function is called in a Ruby on Rails unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am using TestUnit and would like to determine if a function is called.  I have a method in a class called Person which I set to be called 'before_update':

```
def geocode_if_location_info_changed
    if location_info_changed?
      spawn do
        res = geocode
      end
    end
  end
```

Then I have a unit test:

```
def test_geocode_if_location_info_changed
  p = create_test_person
  p.address = "11974 Thurloe Drive"
  p.city = "Baltimore"
  p.region = Region.find_by_name("Maryland")
  p.zip_code = "21093"
  lat1 = p.lat
  lng1 = p.lng

  # this should invoke the active record hook
  # after_update :geocode_if_location_info_changed
  p.save
  lat2 = p.lat
  lng2 = p.lng
  assert_not_nil lat2
  assert_not_nil lng2
  assert lat1 != lat2
  assert lng1 != lng2

  p.address = "4533 Falls Road"
  p.city = "Baltimore"
  p.region = Region.find_by_name("Maryland")
  p.zip_code = "21209"

  # this should invoke the active record hook
  # after_update :geocode_if_location_info_changed
  p.save

  lat3 = p.lat
  lng3 = p.lng
  assert_not_nil lat3
  assert_not_nil lng3
  assert lat2 != lat3
  assert lng2 != lng3
end
```

How can I ensure that the "geocode" method was called?  This is more important for the case where I want to make sure it is not called if location information has not changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use mocha. This tests the logic of your filter:

```
def test_spawn_if_loc_changed
  // set up omitted
  p.save!
  p.loc = new_value
  p.expects(:spawn).times(1)
  p.save!
end

def test_no_spawn_if_no_data_changed
  // set up omitted
  p.save!
  p.other_attribute = new_value
  p.expects(:spawn).times(0)
  p.save!
end
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, although I think you want `p.expects(:geocode_if_location_info_changed).times(1)`. I'm OK with using mocha here. A before filter seems pretty close to a collaborator in my opinion.

Comment: I was trying to test the logic of the before filter, and *spawn* is the first thing inside the if. If you just test the calling of the before filter, you are only testing that the "before_filter" was present and that rails is working... that's good, but it seemed like we're trying to get at the logic within the filter.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I would like to know if "geocode" is called inside spawn.  either way, when I do p.expects(:spawn).times(1), when the program gets to spawn the first time, will it actually be skipped and not called?

Comment: and i guess another option is to do something like Person.any_instance.stubs(:geocode).returns(true)

Comment: I would probably isolate out these behaviors to make sure I got it all right:

To test that geocode is called inside of *#spawn*, you can use a direct call to #geocode_if_location_info_changed: then stub *location_info_changed?* to true, and expectg mock #geocode.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are mock objects (see [Mockobjects](http://mockobjects.com/) and [Mocks aren't stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) for more general info).  RSpec has [support for them](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/), and there are other standalone libraries out there (for example, [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/)), which should help you if you don't need to switch to RSpec.

Comment: What should I mock here?  My person object is the System Under Test and according to Martin Fowler's article, mocks should be used for collaborators.